# Ubuntuにてapt install apache2-devが失敗します

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, apt

#### 実現したいこと

Ubuntuにapache2-devのインストール

#### 前提

Ubuntuにてaptを利用し、apache2-devをインストールしようとしたのですが、エラーが発生してしまいました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install apache2-dev
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得
ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているの
であれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移
動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 libaprutil1-dev : 依存: libldap2-dev
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。
```

#### 試したこと

```
$ sudo apt install -y libldap2-dev
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得
ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているの
であれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移
動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 libldap-dev : 依存: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1) しかし、2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 はインストールされようとしています
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。

$ sudo apt install -y libldap-dev
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
インストールすることができないパッケージがありました。おそらく、あり得
ない状況を要求したか、(不安定版ディストリビューションを使用しているの
であれば) 必要なパッケージがまだ作成されていなかったり Incoming から移
動されていないことが考えられます。
以下の情報がこの問題を解決するために役立つかもしれません:

以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 libldap-dev : 依存: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1) しかし、2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 はインストールされようとしています
E: 問題を解決することができません。壊れた変更禁止パッケージがあります。

$ sudo apt install -y libldap2=2.5.0
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
パッケージ libldap2 は使用できませんが、別のパッケージから参照されます。
これは、パッケージが欠落しているか、廃止されたか、または別のソース
からのみ利用可能であることを意味します。
しかし、以下のパッケージが置き換えます:
  libldap-2.5-0 slapd:i386 libldap-2.5-0:i386 slapd

E: 'libldap2' のバージョン '2.5.0' が見つかりませんでした

sudo apt install -y libldap-dev=2.5.0
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
パッケージ libldap-dev は使用できませんが、別のパッケージから参照されます。
これは、パッケージが欠落しているか、廃止されたか、または別のソース
からのみ利用可能であることを意味します。
しかし、以下のパッケージが置き換えます:
  libldap-dev:i386

E: 'libldap-dev' のバージョン '2.5.0' が見つかりませんでした
```

Web上でエラー内容など色々と調べてみたのですが、見つかりませんでした。

#### 追加

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
アップグレードパッケージを検出しています... 完了
アップグレード: 0 個、新規インストール: 0 個、削除: 0 個、保留: 0 個。

$ apt list libldap*
一覧表示... 完了
libldap-2.5-0/now 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [インストール済み、ローカル]
libldap-2.5-0/jammy-security 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 i386
libldap-common/now 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [インストール済み、ローカル]
libldap-dev/jammy-security 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 amd64
libldap-dev/jammy-security 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 i386
libldap-java/jammy,jammy 5.0.0+dfsg1-1 all
libldap-ocaml-dev/jammy 2.4.2-1build3 amd64
libldap2-dev/jammy-security,jammy-security 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1 all

$ apt show libldap-dev
Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: openldap
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1,599 kB
Provides: libldap2-dev
Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1)
Breaks: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Download-Size: 302 kB
APT-Sources: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
Description: OpenLDAP 開発ライブラリ
 本パッケージは OpenLDAP ライブラリを使用する LDAP アプリケーションの
 開発を可能とします。本パッケージには、ヘッダ、ライブラリ、静的および 動的リンクを可能とするためのリンクが含まれます。

N: 追加レコードが 1 件あります。表示するには '-a' スイッチを付けてください。

$ apt show libldap-dev -a
Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: openldap
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1,599 kB
Provides: libldap2-dev
Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1)
Breaks: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Download-Size: 302 kB
APT-Sources: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
Description: OpenLDAP 開発ライブラリ
 本パッケージは OpenLDAP ライブラリを使用する LDAP アプリケーションの
 開発を可能とします。本パッケージには、ヘッダ、ライブラリ、静的および 動的リンクを可能とするためのリンクが含まれます。

Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: openldap
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1,599 kB
Provides: libldap2-dev
Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3)
Breaks: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Download-Size: 302 kB
APT-Sources: http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: OpenLDAP 開発ライブラリ
 本パッケージは OpenLDAP ライブラリを使用する LDAP アプリケーションの
 開発を可能とします。本パッケージには、ヘッダ、ライブラリ、静的および 動的リンクを可能とするためのリンクが含まれます。

$ apt show libldap-2.5-0
Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: openldap
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 579 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Download-Size: 不明
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: OpenLDAP ライブラリ
 OpenLDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) サーバおよびクライ
 アント用の、ランタイムライブラリです。

N: 追加レコードが 2 件あります。表示するには '-a' スイッチを付けてください。

$ apt show libldap-2.5-0 -a
Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: openldap
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 579 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Download-Size: 不明
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: OpenLDAP ライブラリ
 OpenLDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) サーバおよびクライ
 アント用の、ランタイムライブラリです。

Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: openldap
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 578 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Task: server-minimal, print-server, ubuntu-desktop-minimal, lamp-server, samba-server, ubuntu-desktop, cloud-image, postgresql-server, ubuntu-desktop-raspi, ubuntu-wsl, mail-server, server, ubuntu-server-raspi, kubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop-raspi
Download-Size: 184 kB
APT-Sources: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
Description: OpenLDAP ライブラリ
 OpenLDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) サーバおよびクライ
 アント用の、ランタイムライブラリです。

Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Source: openldap
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 573 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2
Homepage: https://www.openldap.org/
Task: server-minimal, print-server, ubuntu-desktop-minimal, lamp-server, samba-server, ubuntu-desktop, cloud-image, postgresql-server, ubuntu-desktop-raspi, ubuntu-wsl, mail-server, server, ubuntu-server-raspi, kubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop-raspi
Download-Size: 184 kB
APT-Sources: http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
Description: OpenLDAP ライブラリ
 OpenLDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) サーバおよびクライ
 アント用の、ランタイムライブラリです。
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l

$ apache2 -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-03-08T17:32:01
```

どのようにすれば解決できるのでしょうか？
教えていただけたら助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 最新は以下の通り (この回答の時点で)

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

もしかすると Ubuntu 22.04.1 から Ubuntu 22.04.2 に上げることで解決するかもしれません

---

エラーメッセージからは, 以下の askubuntuが参考になるはず

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

その Q＆A には次のような項目が(及びそれ以外にも)記されています

- 存在している hold パッケージは無いか？

  ```bash
  dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
  ```
- `/etc/apt/sources.list` に現在使用している Ubuntu リリースとは異なる Ubuntu リリースのソフトウェア ソースがないことを確認

  - Ubuntu 22.04 ならば "jammy" であり, それ以外の(例えば) "Impish Indri", "Kinetic Kudu" その他が含まれていないこと
- `aptitude` コマンドでインストールしてみる

参考:
① aptitudeでうまくいった例 [Ubuntuで依存関係が壊れている時の対応](https://blog.tizen.moe/entry/2016/02/13/202938)
② `apt install --install-recommends` を使用した例 [apt の「壊れた変更禁止パッケージ」への対処方法](https://marmooo.blogspot.com/2020/01/apt.html)

---

また, パッケージの探し方が間違ってそうです
`libldap2` というパッケージは見当たらない

```bash
$ apt list libldap*
一覧表示... 完了
libldap-2.5-0/jammy-updates,now 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [インストール済み、自動]
libldap-2.5-0/jammy-updates 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386
libldap-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all [インストール済み、自動]
libldap-dev/jammy-updates 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64
libldap-dev/jammy-updates 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 i386
libldap-java/jammy,jammy 5.0.0+dfsg1-1 all
libldap-ocaml-dev/jammy 2.4.2-1build3 amd64
libldap2-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 all
```

`libldap-dev` パッケージ

```bash
$ apt show libldap-dev
Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
 (中略)

N: 追加レコードが 2 件あります。表示するには '-a' スイッチを付けてください。

$ apt show -a libldap-dev
Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
 (中略)
Provides: libldap2-dev
Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
Breaks: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)

Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1
 (中略)
Provides: libldap2-dev
Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1)
Breaks: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)

Package: libldap-dev
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3
 (中略)
Provides: libldap2-dev
Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (= 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3)
Breaks: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
Replaces: libldap2-dev (<< 2.5.4+dfsg-1~)
```

`libldap-2.5-0` パッケージ
(同パッケージに, Version: `2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1`, `2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1`, `2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3` が存在する)

```bash
$ apt show libldap-2.5-0
Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
 (中略)

N: 追加レコードが 2 件あります。表示するには '-a' スイッチを付けてください。
$ apt show -a libldap-2.5-0
Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
 (中略)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2

Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3.1
 (中略)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2

Package: libldap-2.5-0
Version: 2.5.11+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu3
 (中略)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2), libsasl2-2 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg2)
Recommends: libldap-common
Conflicts: ldap-utils (<= 2.1.23-1)
Replaces: libldap-2.3-0, libldap2
```

---

##### 追記

Ubuntu 22.04.2 のポイントリリースに更新できない, ということですが
手元の環境で, もしかすると関係あるかもしれない？ 以下の設定があります

- ダウンロード元: メインサーバー
- アップデートの「確認対象」: すべてのアップデート

Comment: oririさん、ご回答ありがとうございました。参考になりました。申し訳ございません。「Ubuntu 22.04.2 に上げる」にはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？`apt update`や`apt full-ugrade`を試したり、「ソフトウェアの更新」を押してみたのですが22.04.1 LTSから上がりませんでした。 その他の部分は現在試させていただいております。色々と教えていただきありがとうございます。

Comment: oririさん、追記でのご回答ありがとうございました。無事Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTSへUpdateできました。また、質問の問題はご紹介頂いたaptitudeで解決できました。先にaptitudeしてしまったため、Ubuntuのアプデで解決出来るのかわからなくなってしまいましたが、解決は出来ました。本当にありがとうございました。感謝です。